# Sql join for two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am facing an issue while retrieving some data from sql.

I have two table table1 and table2.

Table1 is my master table. Please refer the below table strucure.[image]

Table2 structure

[image]

I need to get a output like

[image]

Please help me

Thanks!

Comment: And these tables are related how...?

Comment: Table2 column names and table 1' s action

Comment: ur images are blocked from viewing

Comment: @chandran pls try now

Comment: imgur is blocked can u use sqlfidle for the schema

Comment: @user2395176 You have nothing in the first table that specifies a UserId.  How do you expect to get the number of badges per user if you can't relate them to the user?  Also, where does the 3 views come from for UserId 3...?  Please specify your relevant table structure, (complete) sample data, and queries you've tried.

Comment: How do u arrive no of badges wher u have only have badges1 and badges2... and tell us if you have tried something and we can help correcting it

Comment: I can't add userid in first table. That's my master table.. my requirement is like if a user have 10 comments. Then he shoud get 2 badges(badge1 and badge2)

Comment: userid and id are related columns?

Comment: @chandran no.. both have no relation

Comment: @user2395176 How on Earth would you have expected anyone to magically figure out that requirement...?   Please update your question with *all relevant information*.

Comment: ur table1 doesn't really say for which userid the badges belong .. did u create this tables?

Comment: @chandran He's saying that the first table is a lookup table to determine what badge a user should get based on the number of likes/comments/views.

Comment: @user2395176 Why aren't the totals for the UserId's not 3, 3, and 2?

Comment: @Siyual sorry I didn't get you

Comment: @user2395176 how do u arrive userid 3 as 5 shouldn't it be 4 since it views is less than 4 we can't add any badge to it

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is very unclear, but based on your comments, you're using `Table1` as a lookup table for the badges received based on the number of Likes, Comments, and Views.

You can do these lookups as a `Cross Apply` for each element:

```
Select  UserId, Likes, Comments, Views, 
        LikeBadges.Count + CommentBadges.Count + ViewBadges.Count As NoOfBadges
From    Table2
Cross Apply
(
    Select  Count(*) as Count
    From    Table1
    Where   Table1.Action = 'Likes'
    And     Table2.Likes >= Table1.Count
) As LikeBadges
Cross Apply
(
    Select  Count(*) as Count
    From    Table1
    Where   Table1.Action = 'Comments'
    And     Table2.Comments >= Table1.Count
) As CommentBadges
Cross Apply
(
    Select  Count(*) as Count
    From    Table1
    Where   Table1.Action = 'Views'
    And     Table2.Views >= Table1.Count
) As ViewBadges
```